# Showing a waiting/loading .jsp page or .gif image while waiting for the results from a rest call

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I have a simple Java application with just two JSP pages. This is a Spring Boot application. When the application starts I have a start.jsp, with a submit button. The user remain on this page (start.jsp), for at least a few minutes (back end formulates the data) and the results are shown in the details.jsp page.

I would like to display a loading .gif image while the back end is being executed. This image works just fine right from the start (when the page is loaded). I would like this image to be hidden and displayed only after the submit button is clicked.

I have the following code in my jsp but want the image to be hidden until the submit button is selected and not sure how to do that.

```
        <div class="loader hidden">
            <img src="/images/loading-2.gif" alt="Loading..." />
        </div>
    
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.addEventListner("load". function(){
            const loader = document.querySelector(".loader");
            console.log(loader);
            loader.classname +=" hidden"; //class "loader hidden"
        })  
        </script>
```

I am new to JSP, and am not familiar with jQuery and Ajax.

Comment: Look for a AJAX tutorial

Comment: Might also look into Server Sent Events

Comment: I am looking for something like this in JS  $(document).ready(function () {
$(".loader").hide();
        $("#btn").on("click",function () {
            //some code
            $(".loader").show();
            $.getJSON(url, (data) => {
                console.log(data);
              $(".loader").hide();
            });

        })
    })

Comment: Hi, did that code works or not ?

Comment: I put the loader image in a div, set the div to display when the submit button of the form is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer worked with a script. Create an EventListner on form submit.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('submit', function(event){
        var gif = document.getElementById("load");  
            
        if (gif.style.display !== "none") 
        {  
            gif.style.display = "none";  
        }  
        else
        {  
            gif.style.display = "block";  
        }     
        event.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById('form').submit();       
    })
</script>
```